# Why does this function not contradict Clairaut's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3y-xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$, defined as 0 at 0 looking at its mixed partial derivatives $\partial_{xy}f,\partial_{yx}f$ specifically and how they don't match.

Comment: Well, there is only *one* hypothesis in Clairaut's Theorem and that's the continuity of partial derivatives at that point. So if not contradicting good chance this hypothesis isn't met...

Comment: $f$ is not of class $C^2$